# P versus NP Clarification

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Quoted from wikipedia, the P vs NP problem, regarding the time complexity of algorithms "... asks whether every problem whose solution can be quickly verified by a computer can also be quickly solved by a computer."

I am hoping that somebody can clarify what the difference between "verifying the problem" and "solving the problem" is here.

Comment: I also don't understand the problem. If you were to verify an answer wouldn't you have to solve it in the first place to be able to compare it?

Comment: @LukeTaylor comparing something to the right solution (or to the set of right solution) is not the only way to verify an answer, in particular for problems with infinite solutions. As example, consider an equation - or even an inequation, it is easier to take a possible solution and evaluate it to see if it that possible solution satisfies the equation than it is to solve the equation in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am hoping that somebody can clarify what the difference between "verifying the problem" and "solving the problem" is here.

It's not *"verifying the **problem**"*, but *"verifying the **solution**"*. For example you can check in polynomial time whether a given set is valid for [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Boolean_satisfiability_problem&oldid=558043033). The actual generation of such set is NP hard. The section [*Verifier-based definition* in the Wikipedia article NP (complexity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=NP_%28complexity%29&oldid=562909910#Verifier-based_definition) could help you a little bit:

> #### Verifier-based definition
>
> In order to explain the verifier-based definition of **NP**, let us consider the subset sum problem: Assume that we are given some integers, such as {−7, −3, −2, 5, 8}, and we wish to know whether some of these integers sum up to zero. In this example, the answer is "yes", since the subset of integers {−3, −2, 5} corresponds to the sum (−3) + (−2) + 5 = 0. The task of deciding whether such a subset with sum zero exists is called the subset sum problem.
>
> As the number of integers that we feed into the algorithm becomes larger, the number of subsets grows exponentially, and in fact the subset sum problem is **NP**-complete. However, notice that, if we are given a particular subset (often called a certificate), we can easily check or verify whether the subset sum is zero, by just summing up the integers of the subset. So if the sum is indeed zero, that particular subset is the proof or witness for the fact that the answer is "yes". An algorithm that verifies whether a given subset has sum zero is called verifier. A problem is said to be in **NP** if and only if there exists a verifier for the problem that executes in polynomial time. In case of the subset sum problem, the verifier needs only polynomial time, for which reason the subset sum problem is in **NP**.

If you're more into graph theory the [Hamilton cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hamiltonian_path&oldid=564480425) is a NP-complete problem. It's trivial to check whether a given solution is a Hamilton cycle (linear complexity, traverse the solution path), but if P != NP than there exists no algorithm with polynomial runtime which solves the problem.

Maybe the term "quick" is misleading in this context. An algorithm is quick in this regard if and only if it's worst-case runtime is bounded by a polynomial function, such as `O(n)` or `O(n log n)`. The creation of all permutations for a given range with the length `n` is not bounded, as you have `n!` different permutations. This means that the problem could be solved in *n <sup>100</sup> log n*, which will take a very long time, but this is still considered fast. On the other hand, one of the first algorithms for TSP was O(n!) and another one was O(n<sup>2</sup> 2<sup>n</sup>). And compared to polynomial functions these things grow really, really fast.

Comment: LOL "verifying the problem" is funny.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, actually sometimes it's rather difficult to explain others that there is any problem at all: *"What do you mean, you didn't go to the grocery store?" - "I tried to calculate a hamilton cyclce through the corridors in order to see everything exactly once, but my program is still running" - "That's ridiculous!" - "No, it's NP complete."*

Answer (score 0):

The RSA encryption uses prime numbers like following: two big prime numbers P and Q (200-400 digits each) are multiplied to form the public key N. `N=P*Q`
To break the encryption one needs to figure out P and Q given the N.
While finding P and Q is very difficult and can take years, verifing the solution is just about multiplying P by Q and comparing with N.
So solving the problem is very hard while it takes nothing to verifying the solution.

P.S. The example is only part of the RSA simplified for this question. The real RSA is much more complex.

Comment: While it has been known for millennia how to multiply (numbers) in polynomial time (and for decades how to do so sub-quadratically), not knowing how to factor fast proves but ignorance (, if shared).