# n! different permutations achievable in n^100 log n

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I was reading this post on SO : [p-versus-np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774968/p-versus-np-clarification)

And saw this:

`"The creation of all permutations for a given range with the length n is not bounded, as you have n! different permutations. This means that the problem could be solved in n^(100) log n, which will take a very long time, but this is still considered fast."`

Can someone explain how n! is solvable in n^(100) log n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I carefully read the statement that comes from a longer explanation that I googled out. I think that the correct wording would be:

"This means that **a** problem could be solved in n 100 log n, which **would** take a very long time, but this is still considered fast. On the other hand, one of the first algorithms for TSP was O(n!) and another one was O(n2 2n). And compared to polynomial functions these things grow really, really fast."

Notice the word "**a**" instead of "**the**"

Answer (score 0):

The correct approximation is the [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

That condradicts what that guys wrote. Honestly, I have no idea what he meant by it...